# Converting type string to long

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to convert the type of string to long in the following code:

```
PaymentReceived = String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN", true), "{0:n}", t.PaymentReceived),
```

Here `t.PaymentReceived` is of type long, and the `PaymentReceived` is of type string but I want it to be of type long.

I am using this to convert the `PaymentReceived` value into comma separated value.
I am trying to do as of my knowledge like

```
PaymentReceived = Convert.ToInt64( String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN", true), "{0:n}", t.PaymentReceived))
```

But the error is **Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.**

So please help me with another solution, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that your `PaymentReceived` formatted well?

Comment: yes i am!!!!! @teovankot

Answer (score 0):

The formatter `n`, adds additional non-numeric characters. For `en-IN` culture, that means a number like `1000` ends up as `1,000.00`.

The `Convert.ToInt64` method requires that the string be 100% numeric, including no period, which might be fine for `Convert.ToDecimal`, but a long is not a float. Therefore, emphatically, your string is *not* formatted correctly, and the error is both obvious and correct. I'm not sure what your ultimate goal here is, but it makes no sense to convert a long to a formatted string and then immediately convert it back to a long, anyways.

Assuming you have only the string and you need to format it as a long, then you need to ensure that it's formatted as a long should be. That requires:

1. Split on the decimal point and take just the left side:

   ```
   str = str.Split(new[] { '.' })[0];
   ```
2. Replace any commas with empty strings:

   ```
   str = str.Replace(",", "");
   ```

That assumes you know the format will something like `1,000.00`. Otherwise, you may want to use a regex to replace all non-numeric characters with an empty string, instead. However, you still need to split on the decimal. Otherwise, if you just removed all non-numeric characters from something like `1,000.00`, then you'd end up with 100000, a number 100 times larger than the actual string number. Also, this is all dependent on the culture. Some cultures use `,` as the decimal separator and `.` and delimiter in large numbers. If you need to handle various cultures, you'll need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: What i am trying is to get the comma separated value into PaymentReceived variable which is of type long. but when i use the syntax like string.format().. the values converts into string which is not expected datatype to store in a table.. so i am trying to convert again it into long ... @ChrisPratt

Comment: Yeah, that isn't much clearer, but regardless, of how or why you end up with a string, you'll have to do some work to it first before you can convert it. See my update above.